# out of memory exception when trying to crop,shift and pad an image

Tags: c#, image

I'm working on a piece of code where I want to be able to crop or shift images. During this I have managed to bring down the problem to the following line of code:

```
Cropped = ScaledImage.Clone(new Rectangle(hscroll, vscroll,ScaledImage.Size.Width, ScaledImage.Size.Height), ScaledImage.PixelFormat);
```

The actual amount of used memory is not big enough to matter (there is no infinite loop and according to the profiler I have plent of memory left (only some 200mB in use troughout the application out of 4 gigs avaible)).

The line of code here is suposed to either pad in front of an image or crop out the left and top side depending on whatever hscroll and vscroll are positive. ScaledImage is a bitMap that is currently 512 by 512.

Comment: What is ScaledImage here?

Comment: A bitmap of size 512 by 512.

Comment: There has to be issue while cloning. What do you get when you step-in?

Comment: I cannot step into the Clone function it seems.

Comment: And Can you please tell me  the values of hscroll and vscroll?

Comment: I'm sure your rectangle is going out of the bitmap. So try this:
new Rectangle(hscroll, vscroll,ScaledImage.Size.Width-hscroll, ScaledImage.Size.Height-vscroll)

Comment: Does this also work if hscroll is negative (in which case I want to pad on the left).

Comment: No it wont. The rectangle has to be within the bitmap region

Comment: And                using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(ScaledImage))
            {
                gr.DrawImageUnscaledAndClipped(ScaledImage,new Rectangle(hscroll,vscroll,ScaledImage.Width-1,ScaledImage.Height-1));
            }
 results in a blank.

Comment: I would recommend asking a new question with that.

Comment: Let's try it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34720558/trying-to-crop-pad-an-image-returns-an-blank-image