# Trying to crop/pad an image returns an blank image

Tags: c#, image, image-processing

I currently have the following code:

```
 using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(ScaledImage))
            {
                gr.DrawImageUnscaledAndClipped(ScaledImage,new Rectangle(hscroll,vscroll,ScaledImage.Width-1,ScaledImage.Height-1));
            }
```

where hscroll and vscroll are the distances I want to pad in front or on top of my image or how much I would like to crop away from them. 
However when hscroll and vscroll are not 0 I get a blank image instead (all values ARGB(0,0,0,0)). 
I also tried

```
Cropped = ScaledImage.Clone(new Rectangle(hscroll, vscroll,ScaledImage.Size.Width, ScaledImage.Size.Height), ScaledImage.PixelFormat);
```

which goes out of memory instead.

Comment: "hscroll and vscroll are not 0" means are they greater than 0 or smaller?

Comment: Bigger or smaller neither works.

Comment: While debugging, can you please tell me what is the size of ScaledImage and the values of hscroll & vscroll.

Comment: ScaledImage has a size of 512 in all of my tests, hscroll and vscroll went wrong in the following pairs: (-10,0) (10,5), (50,-10) and worked on value(0,0).

Comment: In all three cases, the rectangle is going outside the boundary of the graphics object. May I know what exactly is your requirement? Is it cropping or padding?

Comment: The image has to move compared to 0,0. This can be done by padding on the top left or by cropping part of the image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100372/discussion-between-anup-sharma-and-thijser).